# Hibernate Search how to properly search UUID

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have UUID correctly indexed as a whole word by using `PatternTokenizerFactory`, for example `024bb09c-86b4-4d73-8483-bf7839e407d8`.

But when searching, the query with this full string will return an error saying,

```
The query string '024bb09c-86b4-4d73-8483-bf7839e407d8' applied on field 'id' has no meaningfull tokens to be matched. Validate the query input against the Analyzer applied on this field.
```

Does this mean I need to set specific analyzer on preparing the query?

The code that reports this error is as follows,

```
lucene = builder.keyword()
                    .onFields("id", "status", "submitter")
                    .matching(keyword)
                    .createQuery();
```

EDIT:

Here is the Analyzer used for indexing, our raw id is in the form of `group/UUID`, so I use a PatternTokenizer to strip the prefix,

```
@AnalyzerDef(
            name = "idanalyzer",
            tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(
                    factory = PatternTokenizerFactory.class,
                    params = {
                            @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = ".*/(.*)"),
                            @Parameter(name = "group", value = "1")
                    }
            ),
            filters = {
                    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
            }
    )
```

And here is the code in Entity,

```
@Id
@DocumentId
@Analyzer(definition = "idanalyzer")
private String id;
```

Comment: have you looked at this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753642/searching-for-uuid-in-lucene-not-working?

Comment: please share the entity mapping as well, at least how the id is being indexed.

Comment: Sounds like the problem may be that nothing is left of the query once the analyzer is done with it.  What does your analyzer look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution, which is to explicitly specify a `KeywordAnalyzer` to use for the ID query. It's a little tricky to find because originally I was using Hibernate Search DSL code to build up the query, but to use a dedicated analyzer I can only find code with Lucene Parser.

Here is a snippet,

```
            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_31, "instanceId", new KeywordAnalyzer());
            try {
                Query lucene = parser.parse(keyword);
            }
```

And I just add this query to other queries built through Hibernate Search DSL.